# UnsatisfiedLinkError when launching Android app build in Unreal

Tags: android, firebase, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5, oculusquest

I am creating an Android VR app through a custom build of the Oculus Branch, that runs in Oculus Quest 2 and I need to use firebase. But When I launch the app I get this error

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void com.epicgames.unreal.GameActivity.nativeFirInstGetTokenCallback(long, java.lang.String, long, int, java.lang.String) (tried Java_com_epicgames_unreal_GameActivity_nativeFirInstGetTokenCallback and Java_com_epicgames_unreal_GameActivity_nativeFirInstGetTokenCallback__JLjava_lang_String_2JILjava_lang_String_2)
   at com.epicgames.unreal.GameActivity.nativeFirInstGetTokenCallback(GameActivity.java)
   at com.epicgames.unreal.GameActivity.access$300(GameActivity.java:244)
   at com.epicgames.unreal.GameActivity$7.onComplete(GameActivity.java:1007)
   at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzi.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.2:1)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:886)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:227)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7436)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

Any clues what it might be and how to solve it?

Thank you in advance!